# Progress bar for copying file from 'My.resources' VB.net

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, file-copying, my.resources

I am trying to copy a file from 'My.resources' with a progress bar, i have search through many other file copy progress bar scripts but none of them support copying from internal; files. here is my code:

```
Private Sub Install_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Install.Click
    InstallDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = True
    InstallDialog.ShowDialog()
    If Not (IO.Directory.Exists(IO.Path.GetTempPath & "extract")) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(IO.Path.GetTempPath & "extract")
    End If
    If Not (InstallDialog.SelectedPath = "") Then
        Dim exepath As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath & "extract\7zG.exe"
        Dim archpath As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath & "extract\arch.7z"
        If File.Exists(archpath) = False Then
            Dim b As Byte() = My.Resources.arch
            Dim TempFile As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Create(archpath)
            TempFile.Write(b, 0, b.Length)'Copies the archive to disk
            TempFile.Flush()
            TempFile.Close()
        End If
        If File.Exists(exepath) = False Then
            Dim c As Byte() = My.Resources.zipexe
            Dim TempFile As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Create(exepath)
            TempFile.Write(c, 0, c.Length)'Copies the 7-zip executable to disk
            TempFile.Flush()
            TempFile.Close()
        End If
            Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
            p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            p.FileName = exepath
            p.Arguments = " x " & archpath & " -mmt -aoa -o" & InstallDialog.SelectedPath
            Dim Extract As Process = Process.Start(p)'runs 7-zip to extract the archive
            Dim i As Boolean = True
            Do While i = True
                If Extract.HasExited = True Then
                    i = False
                Else
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
                End If
            Loop
            Msgbox("Installation Complete")            
    End If
End Sub
```

my progress bar is called 'copyprog', 
'arch.7z' is about 150Mb and the UI hangs while it's copying, my users are using very slow machines and want to have some response other than the app freezing on button click.

Comment: one reason why your UI hangs: Use of `thread.sleep`. Using this on the UI Thread is almost never a godd idea.

Comment: i have virtually no experience in threading, the reason i have thread.sleep there, is because without it it maxes my CPU usage

Comment: Do you want an "accurate" feedback of whats going on (like "decompressed xx%") or do you just want "some" feedback (like "copying ...", "decompressing ..." etc)?

Comment: I would prefer something like "after x amount of bytes have been copied, update the progress bar" but a percentage value is fine, i only need feedback for the copying process 'Tempfile.write' for the decompression it has 7-zips's GUI

Comment: Use the Process.Exited event instead.  You cannot get progress from an external process.

Comment: i'm not trying to get progress from 7-zip, i'm trying to get progress from the 'Tempfile.write' operations, also how would i go about implementing the Process.Exited event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach (of many) to achieve what you want. This approach leaves the UI alone so it will update fine. I wrote support for two progress-bars, one for total progress (number of files) and one for current progress. The code support cancellation.

Use and modify as you wish, it's provided as-is.

The code assumes as mentioned, two progress bars on the form as well as two buttons (install and cancel) - see snapshot below.

[image: snapshot of demo]

### Usage

You just add to a task-list all the resources you want to copy, then start the cue.

```
AddCopyTask(resourceToCopy1, pathToWhereToCopy1)
AddCopyTask(resourceToCopy2, pathToWhereToCopy2)
...
StartCopyCue()
```

Complete code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    'If you use small file sizes, lower this value to have progress-bar going
    Private Const BufferSize As Integer = 4096

    Private WithEvents bgCopier As New BackgroundWorker

    Private Class WorkerPacket
        Public DataRef As Byte()
        Public Filename As String
    End Class

    Private taskList As New List(Of WorkerPacket)
    Private _cancel As Boolean = False

    '
    '-- Setup worker
    '
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        bgCopier.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bgCopier.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        If bgCopier IsNot Nothing Then
            bgCopier.Dispose()
        End If

    End Sub
    '
    '-- UI
    '
    Private Sub Install_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Install.Click

        '
        '-- This is where you initilize the paths and data you want to copy.
        '-- For this example I use the same data
        '
        AddCopyTask(My.Resources.TestData, "c:\test1.dat")
        AddCopyTask(My.Resources.TestData, "c:\test2.dat")
        AddCopyTask(My.Resources.TestData, "c:\test3.dat")

        StartCopyCue()

    End Sub
    Private Sub CancelCopy_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CancelCopy.Click

        _cancel = True

        If bgCopier.IsBusy Then
            bgCopier.CancelAsync()
        End If

    End Sub
    '
    '-- The methods to build and perform task-list
    '
    Private Sub AddCopyTask(data As Byte(), filename As String)
        '
        '-- Create argument packet for worker
        '
        Dim wp As New WorkerPacket
        wp.DataRef = data
        wp.Filename = filename

        taskList.Add(wp)

    End Sub
    Private Sub StartCopyCue()
        '
        '-- Init total progressbar
        '
        ProgressBarTotal.Value = 0
        ProgressBarTotal.Maximum = taskList.Count

        _cancel = False
        '
        '-- Update UI
        '
        Install.Enabled = False
        CancelCopy.Enabled = True
        '
        '-- Go
        '
        CopyBytesToFileMT()

    End Sub
    Private Sub CopyBytesToFileMT()
        '
        '-- Get work packet
        '
        Dim wp As WorkerPacket = taskList(0)
        '
        '-- Init progress bars
        '
        ProgressBarCurrent.Value = 0
        ProgressBarTotal.Value += 1
        '
        '-- Start worker
        '
        If Not _cancel Then
            Label1.Text = String.Format("Copying {0}...", Path.GetFileName(wp.Filename))
            bgCopier.RunWorkerAsync(wp)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub DoWork(s As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgCopier.DoWork

        Dim wp As WorkerPacket = CType(e.Argument, WorkerPacket)
        '
        '-- Calculate segments
        '
        '   note: byte().length returns integer which means we're limited to 2 Gb files
        '
        Dim length As Integer = wp.DataRef.Length
        Dim segments As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(length / BufferSize))
        Dim leftOver As Integer = length - segments * BufferSize

        Dim bf As Integer = BufferSize
        If bf > length Then bf = length

        Dim fs As New FileStream(wp.Filename,
                                 FileMode.Create,
                                 FileAccess.Write,
                                 FileShare.None)
        '
        '-- Copy blocks
        '
        For i As Integer = 0 To segments - 1
            '
            '-- Cancelled?
            '
            If e.Cancel Then
                leftOver = 0
                Exit For
            End If
            '
            '-- Write a segment to file
            '
            Dim pos As Integer = i * BufferSize
            fs.Write(wp.DataRef, pos, bf)
            '
            '-- Report current progress
            '
            bgCopier.ReportProgress(CInt(pos / length * 100))

        Next
        '
        '-- Copy any remainer
        '
        If leftOver > 0 Then
            fs.Write(wp.DataRef, segments * BufferSize, leftOver)
            bgCopier.ReportProgress(100)
        End If
        '
        '-- Done
        '
        fs.Flush()
        fs.Dispose()

    End Sub
    Private Sub CopyProgress(s As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgCopier.ProgressChanged

        ProgressBarCurrent.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

    End Sub
    Private Sub CopyCompleted(s As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgCopier.RunWorkerCompleted
        '
        '-- Remove task just finished
        '
        taskList.RemoveAt(0)
        '
        '-- Do we have another task?
        '
        If taskList.Count > 0 AndAlso Not _cancel Then
            CopyBytesToFileMT()
        Else
            If _cancel Then
                Label1.Text = "Cancelled by user."
            Else
                Label1.Text = "Completed!"
                '
                '-- Execute other tasks here...
                '
            End If
            '
            '-- Update UI
            '
            CancelCopy.Enabled = False
            Install.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Update:** The following modification runs a process after the copy tasks has completed. Modify as needed.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security

Public Class Form1

    Private Event AllCompleted()

    Private Const BufferSize As Integer = 4096

    Private WithEvents bgCopier As New BackgroundWorker
    Private WithEvents procUnzipper As New Process

    Private Class WorkerPacket
        Public DataRef As Byte()
        Public Filename As String
    End Class

    Private taskList As New List(Of WorkerPacket)
    Private _cancel As Boolean = False

    '
    '-- Setup worker
    '
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        bgCopier.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bgCopier.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

        procUnzipper.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        procUnzipper.SynchronizingObject = Me

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        bgCopier.Dispose()
        procUnzipper.Dispose()

    End Sub
    '
    '-- UI
    '
    Private Sub Install_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Install.Click
        '
        '-- This is where you initilize the paths and data you want to copy.
        '-- For this example I use the same data
        '
        AddCopyTask(My.Resources.TestData, "c:\test1.dat")
        AddCopyTask(My.Resources.TestData, "c:\test2.dat")
        AddCopyTask(My.Resources.TestData, "c:\test3.dat")

        StartCopyQue()

    End Sub
    Private Sub CancelCopy_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CancelCopy.Click

        _cancel = True

        If bgCopier.IsBusy Then
            bgCopier.CancelAsync()
        End If

    End Sub
    '
    '-- The methods to build and perform task-list
    '
    Private Sub AddCopyTask(data As Byte(), filename As String)
        '
        '-- Create argument packet for worker
        '
        Dim wp As New WorkerPacket
        wp.DataRef = data
        wp.Filename = filename

        taskList.Add(wp)

    End Sub
    Private Sub StartCopyQue()
        '
        '-- Init total progressbar
        '
        ProgressBarTotal.Value = 0
        ProgressBarTotal.Maximum = taskList.Count

        _cancel = False

        '
        '-- Update UI
        '
        Install.Enabled = False
        CancelCopy.Enabled = True
        '
        '-- Go
        '
        CopyBytesToFileMT()

    End Sub
    Private Sub CopyBytesToFileMT()
        '
        '-- Get work packet
        '
        Dim wp As WorkerPacket = taskList(0)
        '
        '-- Init progress bars
        '
        ProgressBarCurrent.Value = 0
        ProgressBarTotal.Value += 1
        '
        '-- Start worker
        '
        If Not _cancel Then
            Label1.Text = String.Format("Copying {0}...", Path.GetFileName(wp.Filename))
            bgCopier.RunWorkerAsync(wp)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub DoWork(s As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgCopier.DoWork

        Dim wp As WorkerPacket = CType(e.Argument, WorkerPacket)
        '
        '-- Calculate segments
        '
        '   note: byte().length returns integer which means we're limited to 2 Gb files
        '
        Dim length As Integer = wp.DataRef.Length
        Dim segments As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(length / BufferSize))
        Dim leftOver As Integer = length - segments * BufferSize

        Dim bf As Integer = BufferSize
        If bf > length Then bf = length

        Dim fs As New FileStream(wp.Filename,
                                 FileMode.Create,
                                 FileAccess.Write,
                                 FileShare.None)
        '
        '-- Copy blocks
        '
        For i As Integer = 0 To segments - 1
            '
            '-- Cancelled?
            '
            If e.Cancel Then
                leftOver = 0
                Exit For
            End If
            '
            '-- Write a segment to file
            '
            Dim pos As Integer = i * BufferSize
            fs.Write(wp.DataRef, pos, bf)
            '
            '-- Report current progress
            '
            bgCopier.ReportProgress(CInt(pos / length * 100))

        Next
        '
        '-- Copy any remainer
        '
        If leftOver > 0 Then
            fs.Write(wp.DataRef, segments * BufferSize, leftOver)
            bgCopier.ReportProgress(100)
        End If
        '
        '-- Done
        '
        fs.Flush()
        fs.Dispose()

    End Sub
    Private Sub CopyProgress(s As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgCopier.ProgressChanged

        ProgressBarCurrent.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

    End Sub
    Private Sub CopyCompleted(s As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgCopier.RunWorkerCompleted
        '
        '-- Remove task just finished
        '
        taskList.RemoveAt(0)
        '
        '-- Do we have another task?
        '
        If taskList.Count > 0 AndAlso Not _cancel Then
            CopyBytesToFileMT()
        Else
            If _cancel Then
                Label1.Text = "Cancelled by user."
            Else
                Label1.Text = "Unzipping..."
                '
                '-- Start process
                '
                ProgressBarTotal.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee

                Dim arg As String = String.Format(" x ""{0}"" -mmt -aoa -o ""{1}""",
                                                  "theZipFile.7z",
                                                  "installpath\")

                procUnzipper.StartInfo.FileName = "...\7z.exe"
                procUnzipper.StartInfo.Arguments = arg
                procUnzipper.Start()

            End If

        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub UnzipCompleted(s As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles procUnzipper.Exited

        'just for example
        'this following require syncronizationobject set, see form_load
        RaiseEvent AllCompleted()

    End Sub
    Private Sub Done() Handles Me.AllCompleted
        '
        '-- Update UI
        '
        Label1.Text = "Completed!"

        ProgressBarTotal.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks
        CancelCopy.Enabled = False
        Install.Enabled = True

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: but how do i make it launch 7-zip after both file have been copied? at the moment if i add the 7-zip instruction's to the 'copycompleted' sub, it runs 7-zip twice

Comment: You can run it from within the if-else-block where it says completed. That will run it just once.

Comment: I added a modified version which starts a process after copy has completed. This will take care of the last bit (unzipping).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VS2012 and/or the Async feature, it's more or less simple. Note, that as usual, there a dozens of "valid" solutions to your given problem!

```
    ' Write a file with progressbar updates

    Dim output(1000 * 1000) As Byte ' the bytes to be written
    Dim numbytes As Integer = 4096 ' number of bytes per write command

    Using fs As New FileStream("path", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
        Dim outpointer As Integer = 0
        While outpointer <> output.Length
            numbytes = Math.Min(numbytes, output.Length - outpointer)
            Await fs.WriteAsync(output, outpointer, numbytes)
            outpointer += numbytes
            ProgressBar1.Value = (outpointer * 100) \ output.Length
        End While
        Await fs.FlushAsync
    End Using

    ' Wait for a process to be done
    Dim p As New Process With {.EnableRaisingEvents = True, .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")}
    Dim cts As New CancellationTokenSource
    Dim exithandler = Sub(prc As Object, ev As EventArgs)
                          cts.Cancel()
                      End Sub
    AddHandler p.Exited, exithandler

    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
    p.Start()

    Try
        Dim t = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cts.Token)
        Await t
        If t.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then
            MessageBox.Show("Process still executing! Might be an error! What can we do?")
        End If
    Catch ex As TaskCanceledException
        ' thats ok! we WANT the task to be cancelled!
    End Try

    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum

    MessageBox.Show("all done!")
```

The main advantage: It's all in one sub, and the flow is more or less linear. If you use a library like sevenzipsharp (or any other that fits), you gould even get progress feedback on decompression (i think). if you want to stick with an external exe you might try if you can check the filelength in a loop to offer feedback on decompression.